# Race Condition in Python Loop

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, race-condition

I have a loop for finding sum value. My task to make the loop parallel.
Problem: loop using arays where i - element depends on i - 1.
So at each iteration we must have (i) and (i-1) value.
That's my code:

```
def sumLoss(xs, hs, ys, ps, t):

  xs[t] = np.zeros((vocab_size,1)) # encode in 1-of-k representation
  xs[t][inputs[t]] = 1
  hs[t] = np.tanh(np.dot(Wxh, xs[t]) + np.dot(Whh, hs[t-1]) + bh) # hidden state
  ys[t] = np.dot(Why, hs[t]) + by # unnormalized log probabilities for next chars
  ps[t] = np.exp(ys[t]) / np.sum(np.exp(ys[t])) # probabilities for next chars

  return -np.log(ps[t][targets[t],0])
```

And that's my pathetic attempts of solving task:

```
res = Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(sumLoss)(xs, hs, ys, ps, t) for t in range(len(inputs)))
```

Of course it's a completely wrong decision, and I am not familiar with synchronization primitives.

Comment: It would help if you gave an example of an input and what output you'd expect from it and what the problem is now. Also a minimal example that can actually be run. I'm guessing you're using numpy and the joblib library but a lot of your variables aren't defined in your code. What is `Wxh` for example?

Comment: Input - any txt-file with English text, program - simple RNN implementation ~ 150 lines. Yeah, i'm try to use joblib. My source code - https://gist.github.com/MrLebovsky/79954b733cda6d0c0d7bc759d2a4d8e5

Comment: @AndrewMcDowell Is it possible to implement this algorithm in parallel?

Comment: I'm afraid I still can't follow what your code is trying to do, so I'm not sure. If it's a task where result i depends on result i-1, then I think the answer is going to be no as you can't complete these tasks in parallel. Each one will depend on the previous one finishing.